# How to analyze Android Service tasks with the new Google analytics for mobile (v2)

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-service

I do **NOT** have a foreground activity - just a background [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) (kind of a keep-alive service).

How do I use the [new analytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/) with it?

Answer (score 0):

On the `onCreate()` method of your Service, you could try:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
```

This way, you can use EasyTracker outside of an Activity.

Comment: Consider the case of using some kind of an abstraction code that doesn't really care if it's run in an activity or service. Can I use the application context?

Comment: I guess you can but I don't really know, it depends on the abstraction code I guess. Just try :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two classes in the SiFEUP mobile client. They give a nice example of managing a single thread to make your tracking calls on, as well as session management. You should be able to use the [AnalyticsUtils](http://code.google.com/p/sifeup-mobile/source/browse/SiFEUPMobile/src/pt/up/beta/mobile/tracker/AnalyticsUtils.java) class for your service.

http://code.google.com/p/sifeup-mobile/source/browse/SiFEUPMobile/src/pt/up/beta/mobile/tracker/

Answer (score 0):

You can use new google analytics to do this.

```
GoogleAnalytics GaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext);
Tracker tracker = GaInstance.getTracker("UA-XXXX-Y");
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
        .setCategory(categoryId) // string value of Category name
        .setAction(actionId)     // string value of action name
        .setLabel(labelId)      // string value of  label name
        .build());
```